# KnockoutJS - binding child component's click event in parent's markup

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js, template-engine

I am trying to write a reusable component library, and have come up with this issue which is bugging me for a time now.

I have overriden the template engine using the [example](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/10/ko-13-preview-part-3-template-sources.html) that is provided. I think my problem is mentioned in his 'A quick note about rewriting templates' paragraph (I am not sure though, my problem might be different). But I don't have any idea how to implement it. Any help is appreciated. Here's the problem:

My template engine basically registers templates given as 'templateName' and 'markUp'. Firstly, I have a product model, which goes as:

```
 var Product = function(img, brand, description){
      this.img = img;
      this.brand = brand;
      this.description = description;
 };
```

Then, I have my parent view as:

```
{
    name: 'productlist-view',
    template:  '<productlist-view class="product-list">\
            <ul data-bind="foreach: {data: productlist, as: \'product\'}">\
                <product-box params="parent: $parent, productInfo: product" data-bind="click: getProduct"></product-box>\
            </ul>\
        </productlist-view>'
}
```

Now in the viewModel of this `productlist-view` view, `productlist` property is defined as an array of `Product` instances. The `product-box` component is supposed to create a viewModel and an associated template for each of these `Product`s. The product-box component is registered to knockout using:

```
ko.components.register('product-box', {
    'viewModel': function(params){
          this.product = params.product;

          this.getProduct = function(){
               //Will perform an ajax call here
          };
     },
    'template': '<div class="product-box" data-bind="click: getProduct">\
                     <img class="product-img fl" data-bind="attr: {src: product.img}"/>\
                     <p data-bind="text: product.brand"></p>\
                     <p data-bind="text: product.description"></p>\
                 </div>'
})
```

I know, in the code above there are two bindings for the `getProduct` method. I will come to that. For now, just imagine the one in the productlist-view was not there.

The code above generates an html that goes like:

```
<productlist-view ....
    <ul .... 
        <product-box ....
             <div class="product-box" ....
                  <img .../>
                  <p ...  />
                  <p ...  />
             </div>
        </product-box>
        <product-box ..... goes on
    </ul>
</productlist-view>
```

In the above-code, the wrapper `div` in `the product-box` element is totally unnecessary since it just wraps the element. Moreover, the element is already wrapped within `product-box` element. So I want to remove the wrapper div. **The problem here is that, I need the whole product visual to be clickable, but I cannot bind the click event to the getProduct method from the productlist-view template.** When the `foreach` loop iterates in `productlist-view` template, the $data points to model of the **product**, not the `viewModel` (aka product-box).

How can I set this getProduct method, from the parent view?

Is there anyway to remove that unnecessary wrapper div in product-box?

In other words how can I have a clickable product-box component which goes like:

```
<productlist-view ....
    <ul .... 
        <product-box data-bind="click: getProduct"....
             <img .../>
             <p ...  />
             <p ...  />
        </product-box>
        ...
    </ul>
</productlist-view>
```

Comment: Perhaps you could pass a callback in the params, e.g. `params="getProductCallback: myCallback"` and have the click in your component use that callback?

Comment: But that would not solve my 'wrapper div' problem, does it? The whole product-box need to be clickable. Where would you suggest I write 'data-bind="click: ..." ' expression?

Comment: The custom element you use for a component will not translate 1-on-1 to a DOM element anyways. You need to either wrap the component in an (e.g. `div`) element and bind click there, or make the top level DOM element in your component (e.g. a `div`) handle the click. No other solution, AFAIK.

Comment: Working around by wrapping the component in a `div` element, defeats all the purpose of componentization. What I want to have a productlist element which is composed of just `product-box`es. Adding a div in-between just seems cheesy. There's gotta be a nicer way to do that :( What you suggest implies that the parent must handle the getProduct function. I have thought about this, but then the getProduct function will check the $index to locate the clicked product. Now then, why did I bother with writing a product-box component to begin with... I think you see the point. Thanks for you help

Comment: Custom elements will just not be rendered themselves in the DOM, and can *not* handle clicks. Nothing either of us can do about that ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* make a custom binding handler that would attach a click binding to the parent, but that strikes me as too clever by half (and violates encapsulation). If your `click` binding is associated with your component, it makes sense that the `div` be part of the component.
Instead of using custom product-box tags, you can use a [virtual tag and the `component` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-binding.html#note-using-component-without-a-container-element), so you don't have an extraneous wrapper.

Comment: Hey your suggestion actually works out nicer than what it is right now. Although now the Dom is cluttered with `<!-- ko..` tags, the structure is right at least. I made the component's template name as `product-box-template`, and in the actual component I use a wrapper which is a `product-box` tag. This way, there are only `product-box`es inside the `productlist-view`. Thanks for your help, I believe this solves my problem!